# When casting spells, must you provide all of the components?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spell-components

I'm sure this is a basic answer and quite a dumb question, but I really am confused on the matter. When you cast a spell, do you have to provide every component to it, or can you settle for just one, unless otherwise specified (such as a specified gp amount material). For example, a spell with VS components; is such a spell able to be casted simply by speaking the verbal component, or must you speak while performing the somatic components as well?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## Spell components are all-or-nothing...

If you can't complete them all, you can't cast the spell.

> If you can’t provide one or more of a spell’s components, you are unable to cast the spell. - "Components", *PHB* p 203 or [Components on D&D Beyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/spellcasting#Components)

## ...but there are ways around them.

Depending on the exact class, there are options for the material components - a spellcasting focus can substitute for them. Ranger is notable for not having access to a spellcasting focus, and will always need a component pouch or the specific component.

Sorcerers (with [Subtle Spell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/sorcerer#SubtleSpell)) and Druids (at L20 via [Archdruid](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/druid#Archdruid)) can get around verbal and somatic components, but pretty much everybody else is stuck with them.

[Spells cast from magic items](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/magic-items#Spells) don't need the components at all, though the specific item may impose other requirements.

Answer (score 13):

## Spellcasting Components

You have to provide all indicated components

> If you can't provide one or more of a spell's components, you are unable to cast the spell.

<sub>(PHB, p. 203)</sub>

## Exceptions

There are ways to bypass those components, here are some (no guarantee for completeness)

#### Verbal (V)

- A sorcerer with the *subtle spell* meta-magic
- A level 20 druid with the *Archdruid* class feature

#### Somatic (S)

- A sorcerer with the *subtle spell* meta-magic
- A level 20 druid with the *Archdruid* class feature
- Any spellcaster with the *War Caster* feat can not really bypass this requirement, but they can also use hands occupied by a weapon or shield

#### Material (M)

- If you have a *component pouch*, a *spellcasting focus* or a *holy symbol* (depends on your class), you can ignore all material components which have no indicated costs
- If you cast a spell from a *spell scroll* you do not have to have the material components
- A *way of the four elements* monk does not have to provide material components for their elemental spells. <sub>(PHB, p. 80)</sub>

#### All of them

- There are some monsters which can cast spells with their *innate spellcasting ability* they do not have to provide any components.
- Unless stated otherwise if you cast a spell from an item you can do so without any components. <sub>(DMG, p. 141)</sub>

Comment: Another way to ignore Material and Somatic components is the _Wish_ spell,which can duplicate any 8th level or lower spell with no need for components. (_Wish_ itself requires a Verbal component)

Comment: There's a small fault in the Material section: pouches and focuses also cannot replace components that will be used up. Not all components with a gp price are used up and vice versa.

Comment: @TBP in the equipment chapter it explicitly says that a component pouch replaces all material components except for those that have a specific cost. Independent of consumption or not.

Comment: Might be another difference betwenn a focus and a pouch I'd overlooked so far. I'll check once I get my hands on my PHB.

Comment: @TBP The spellcasting chapter mentions that you have to provide consumed materials for each casting, but this does not exclude the pouch from replacing/providing them, as long as they have no specific cost. I am not sure if same applies to foci, though. I would think yes.

Comment: @Thyzer I know I've read that exact limitation last week with my players, so unless it's a limitation of foci, there is something wonky with the German translation of their PHB. :)

Comment: @TBP *"A character can use a **component pouch** or a **spellcasting focus** in place of the components specified for a spell. But if a cost is indicated for a component, a character must have that specific component before he or she can cast the spell."* - No limitation regarding whether those components are later consumed or not.

Comment: @Thyzer: The relevant bit is the sentence immediately after that one: ["If a spell states that a material component is consumed by the spell, the caster must provide this component for each casting of the spell."](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#MaterialM) Rules designer Jeremy Crawford [unofficially confirms this here](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2015/01/15/material-component-and-spellcasting-focus/).

Answer (score 5):

#### Yes. Spell casting requires all listed components casting, generally ...

Unless you have a holy symbol or arcane focus, which can substitute for some material components, you need to speak the words (Verbal) and make the motions(Somatic), and maybe dig into your component pouch for a spell component (Material), in order to cast the spell.

> If you can't provide one or more of the spell's components, you can't
>   cast the spell.(PHB p. 203)

This creates some obstacles to casting if you are, for example, under a *silence* spell.  Unless you can get the verbal components to work, the spell won't work.

#### How do you get around the requirements?

1. Play a Sorcerer or a (20th level) Druid

   The Sorcerer has a metamagic option called "subtle spell" that (if chosen) allows the Sorcerer to get around the requirement for somatic or verbal components (PHB p. 102) but most other spell casters don't have access to that workaround.

   > At 20th level...you can ignore the verbal and somatic Components of
   >   your druid Spells, as well as any material Components that lack a cost
   >   and aren't consumed by a spell. You gain this benefit in both your
   >   normal shape and your beast shape from Wild Shape." PHB pg 68
2. Ring of Spell Storing

   Another way around this problem is via the ring of spell storing.  (DMG p. 192). 
   That item has to have the spell cast into it in the normal manner, (which requires all of the components be present) but when it's time for you to use the spell, you simply cast it from the ring.  It is limited to five total spell levels, so spells of level 6-9 can't be stored in that item.
3. Use a scroll

   > If the spell is on your class's spell list, you can use an action to
   >   read the scroll, and cast its spell without having to provide any of
   >   the spell's components. (DMG p. 200)

   The text of the description for scrolls indicates that you need to read it, but it does not specify that you need to read it aloud.  (DMG p. 139).  (This is something you may need to work out with your DM).
4. Cast a spell from a magic item

   Casting the spell from a magic item (like a wand) also overcomes the need for a spell component's use.

   > The spell is cast at the lowest possible spell level,  doesn't expend
   >   any of the user's spell slots, and requires no components unless the
   >   item's description says otherwise. (DMG p. 141).
5. At high level, cast a spell (8th level or lower) by using the *wish* spell to avoid using material / somatic components. (Wish still requires the verbal component).