# Are there any spells that do not have any components?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spell-components

In my discussion over my method answering [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/112800/37348), I assumed that there aren't any spells that have no components.  Without being able to look through the entire set of rules myself (and as a possible hook for future discussions of the matter) I am looking for a counter example.

Is there an official (or UA) spell that does not require at-least 1 component?  If so which one(s)?

Stated differently is there a spell that when put into a program like app.roll20.com would leave material components unchecked, somatic components unchecked, and verbal components unchecked?

Just for clarification this would be before effects such as Subtle Spell or Archdruid.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

## There are no official spells that have no components

Every spell in officially released material right now has 1 or more components.

It is difficult to cite this but I found this by doing a [search](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells?filter-class=0&filter-search=&filter-verbal=f&filter-somatic=f&filter-material=f&filter-concentration=&filter-ritual=&filter-sub-class=) on dndbeyond.com using those parameters and no results come up even with all the material at hand.

I also recently did a manual search through all the spells to the same result.

Answer (score 14):

### All official spells have at least one component.

Using the spell search function in D&D Beyond to [look for spells with no components at all](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells?filter-class=0&filter-search=&filter-verbal=f&filter-somatic=f&filter-material=f&filter-concentration=&filter-ritual=&filter-sub-class=), what you're seeking does not exist. Every spell in the game has at least one of the three.