# What happens if I try to use a magical piece of ammunition/thrown weapon as a spell component for the Conjure Volley spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, spell-components

The spell *conjure volley* has **one piece of ammunition or one thrown weapon** as its material component. The spell effect further describe the requirement of the said ammunition or thrown weapon: they must be nonmagical.

> You fire a piece of nonmagical ammunition from a ranged weapon or throw a nonmagical weapon into the air and choose a point within range. Hundreds of duplicates of the ammunition or weapon fall in a volley from above and then disappear.

**What happens if I use magical ammunition or magical thrown weapon?** Do the spell fail and the spell slot consumed? Do the spell just don't get cast at all and I'm like an idiot throwing a magical axe into the air waiting for something to happen?

Comment: Does this answer your question: "[When casting spells, must you provide all of the components?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/105123)"

Comment: On the other hand, I find it amusing to imagine casting *conjure volley* or *conjure barrage* with common household objects, such as silverware or a vase.

Comment: @RyanC.Thompson And now I'm wondering whether *that* works as well, because it's not a weapon *until* you attack with it so... hmmm

Comment: @Medix2 I disagree with that, there is no clause saying that an improvised weapon is only a weapon when you attack. In fact, it seems to say that the vase is an improvised weapon while it sits peacefully on the table. Note that the weapon does not need the thrown property either. Conjure Volley of vases does not have any obvious problems at least.

Comment: @jgn Well, there are at least Q/A's assuming different ways. Such as not assuming that every object is always a weapon: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/119926, but I see your point. The following also discusses it: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/98283

Comment: Food for thought: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/121614/38834 - The verbal component of _Command_ is not the command word. So there is precedent of the component and the spell being different. So it might be possible to use a magic dagger as the component, but you're still required to produce something non-magical to throw.

Comment: @Medix2 JC aside, I don't see any rules justification. But that's a question for another time.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## The spell doesn't work

Spell text is not flavor, it is rules. If you do not follow the instructions, then no spell takes place.

No spell slots are consumed, the spell doesn't cast, whether or not you look like an idiot is up to you (roll Charisma perhaps?).

Comment: The following quote might help: "If you can’t provide one or more of a spell’s components, you are unable to cast the spell. - "Components", *PHB* p 203 or [D&D Beyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/spellcasting#Components)"

Comment: @Medix2 I'm not 100% convinced about this, is the nonmagical ammunition the ammunition mentioned in the components? Even if it is, the problem is still that you need to follow the rules.

Comment: The components are at least listed as "V, S, M (one piece of ammunition or one thrown weapon)" which... doesn't actually specify non-magical hmmmmmmm

Comment: @Medix2 Humor me then, I have a magical dagger that I am using as the material component. Since it fits the component requirements, does that mean I can use it as the ammunition to create the volley? In my opinion no, regardless of the material component, you need to use a nonmagical ammunition/thrown weapon.

Comment: Yeah I can see what you mean there... definitely not the ideal wording for the spell. Your answer covers it then, though I may open a new question now XD